# Caching downloads for the offline app

Tags: html, caching, offline

I'm building a website with the offline capability. I'm caching various content in various caches (JSON in localStorage, images in regular HTTP cache, website itself in the application cache, etc).

The only problem are file downloads. I want the file, that user has downloaded at least once, to be still available through the HTTP cache when user is offline - i.e. I want to serve downloads from cache.

But whatever I try, e.g.:

```
Cache-Control:       max-age=86400, private
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="presentation.pptx"
Content-Length:      128000
Content-Type:        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
Server:              Microsoft-IIS/8.0
```

when I go offline and request a file download, site still tries to reach online site (and fails).

Any solutions? Is it at all possible?

Thank you in advance.